# Sendgrid get all delivered email using web API

Tags: sendgrid

I've checked the sendgrid api documentation but I could not find the way I can get all delivered email using web api.
Can you send me the link? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, SendGrid doesn't have an API endpoint to achieve this. You'll need to write your own solution to accept calls from their event webhooks (and set them up) and then persist the data yourself.

Starting information on their Event Webhooks: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html